# Call Scheduler after method

Tags: java, spring, task, scheduler

I have an app, which connects to an API every day and fetches a data (schedulers run every 24h). I would like to add such a functionality:
after user registration call schedulers and force fetching data right now. Could you recommend the best approach in Spring?

```
@Component
public class GetMyFeeEstimateScheduler extends Scheduler {

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = DELAY)
@Transactional
public void fetchGetMyFeeEstimate() throws Exception {
    fetchData();
}
```

---

```
 @PostMapping("/signup")
public void signUp(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
  // ...
  // CALL_SCHEDULERS
}
```

Comment: Inject the `GetMyFeeEstimateScheduler` and just call the method.

Comment: As far as I can see `GetMyFeeEstimateScheduler` is a component, simply autowire that into the controller and call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to expose the `fetchData()` as a public method in a service class and then call from the controller and from scheduler.

Another option is to call `fetchGetMyFeeEstimate` directly from the controller.